# How to avoid number repetition

Tags: c#, hashtable

```
Hashtable values = new Hashtable();

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int newval = r.Next(10);

    values.Add("key",newval);


    //foreach (object value in values.Values)
    //{
    //    Response.Write(value.ToString());
    //}


    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(values.Values);
    foreach (int key in arrayList)
    {
        Response.Write(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your asking "When generating a random set of integers how can I insure that I do not have any duplicate numbers?" Is that correct?

Comment: Do you want to avoid repeated keys or values?  When do you want to avoid them - when you're adding to the Hashtable, or when you're writing them out from the ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's random.  By definition there exists a statistical possibility that numbers will repeat.  It's possible that you can add 10 random integers from 1-10 to a list and that they wouldn't repeat, but it would be unlikely.

Ideally, each time you call a randomization function, you have exactly the same odds of getting any one number as you do of getting any other number, including the number you got last time.

Answer (score 2):

If you have *n* values you want to support and you only want them to be used once, a common technique is to shuffle those values in advance and then simply return them sequentially. Otherwise, you'll have higher and higher probability of collision with each successive value that is consumed.

Look into shuffling algorithms such as Fisher-Yates.

Comment: I'd say this is the best answer, but what would you do for massive random numbers in which shuffling would be too resourceful, and would outweigh checking already chosen numbers. What then?!

Answer (score 1):

Also note that when random is created like this:

```
Random r = new Random(); int newval = r.Next(10);
```

the class is initialized with current-time-based value. If you put this code in a loop then you will notice that newval is changed only few times per second.

It's better to create Random instance once and reuse it each time you need new random number.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want values to repeat - you could perform a check prior to adding them to see if the new value is contained in the current set of values (*if this is what you are asking*)

**If you want to avoid adding in duplicate values - into values you could do this:**

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int newval = r.Next(10);

    //Checks for containment
    if(!values.Contains(newval))
    {
        values.Add("key",newval);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your hashtable before adding values into it and re-generate. You would end up with a recursive function then!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you're using `Hashtable` rather than [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)? With `HashSet<int>`, you can easily generate `N` unique random numbers:

```
HashSet<int> Keys = new HashSet<int>();
Random rnd = new Random();
while (Keys.Count < 10)
{
    Keys.Add(rnd.Next(10));
}
```

The `Add` method will return `false` if the value to be added is already in the collection, and that value won't be added again.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, create `Random` instance outside the handler.

```
Random r = new Random();
Hashtable values = new Hashtable();

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int newval = r.Next(10);

    values.Add("key",newval);


    //foreach (object value in values.Values)
    //{
    //    Response.Write(value.ToString());
    //}


    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(values.Values);
    foreach (int key in arrayList)
    {
        Response.Write(key);
    }
}
```